# Office 365 OUTLOOK crashes after send/receive completed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, crash

Office 365 OUTLOOK crashes immediately after send/receive complete. Worked for couple of weeks then prob.

When online it sends and receives mail but then closes with a BEX error message.

When offline the programme is stable.
Safe mode doesn't help and DEP setting cannot be changed.
All add-ins removed
AVG Anti-virus disabled

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A number of email accounts are received through my Outlook app. The program was stable offline but crashed after send/receive.

1. Go into Work Offline mode (I had to customize the ribbon to easily access this command)
2. Go to SEND/RECEIVE tab at very top of Outlook screen
3. Click on Send/Receive pull down menu
4. Click on Define send/Receive Groups
5. With All Accounts highlighted click Edit button
6. Assuming more than one account, select all but one in turn by highlighting it the untick box at top of this dialogue window
7. Stay in off-line mode but press send/receive button

   Prog will send/receive but won’t crash unless there is a prob with the account which is left in the group. Accounts temporarily disabled from send/receive in the group will have a little red cross bottom right.
8. Reintroduce each account in turn until you find the one causing the prob.
   Leave that account out of the group and back out of all the dialogue options.
9. Find location of PST file for problem account. Rename it oldaccountname.pst or archive it.
10. Open new account for the account concerned from FILE > Add Account menu.

This doesn’t determine what it was about the problem account which caused the prob but I am prepared to worry about that another day. If need be the problem account can still be accessed through webmail with a browser.

There are obviously a lot of reasons why Outlook might crash but this was one I had not seen discussed with the way to overcome it. I hope this helps someone. It took me eight hours to get to this.